# Open a new tab from an angular application with some data that needs to be shown in the new tab

Tags: javascript, html, angular, frontend, angular8

I have an angular application, one of the component shows data according to the options selected.
Now from one of the other page i need to open this page in a new tab. 
I tried with href and window.open(url) but whenever i m opening the url in a new tab, all the data gets reset.

I am trying to achieve a way that my selection remains present in the new tab also.

```
goToNewTab(){
 this.selectedYear = [2020,2021,2022]
 const url = "demo-project/checkBirth"
 window.open(url, '_blank')
}
```

Here i need "this.selectedYear" to go to the new tab also.

Please note:- I can't update the url and pass any query params in it with selected year. The url needs to be same.

Comment: Can you use the fragment, like `demo-project/checkBirth#selectedYear=2020`?

Comment: no can't change anything in the url @Thomas

Comment: add it in sessionStorage or LocalStorage

Comment: I think there is only two way either you have to pass value into url (i.e. query param ) or you have to store into local storage. @AchalUtkarsh you can reset url after page load if you go with first solution.

Answer (score 0):

Add it in session storage

```
sessionStorage.setItem("selectedYear", this.selectedYear);
```

and extract it on initial load

```
 return sessionStorage.getItem("selectedYear");
```

Comment: Okay so i checked , the setItem() is having key value pair that can only be string , now if i need to send multiple years , i will have to concat it all to a string , then break it in my next component, any other approach if there are multiple years to be sent

Answer (score 0):

Since your requirement is to open the given URL in a new tab, without the use of parameterized routing, I would recommend you to use localStorage, as sessionStorage exists only within the current browser tab.

You can do the following,

```
goToNewTab() {
this.selectedYear = 2020;
localStorage.setItem("selectedYear", 2020);
const url = "demo-project/checkBirth";
window.open(url, '_blank'); }
```

And within the constructor function of the component class that gets opened in the new tab, you can do the following,

```
constructor() { this.yearOfBirth = localStorage.getItem('selectedYear') }
```

Having said that, another approach can be of calling a shared singleton service between the two components for extracting the values.

Comment: Okay so i checked , the setItem() is having key value pair that can only be string , now if i need to send multiple years , i will have to concat it all to a string , then break it in my next component, any other approach if there are multiple years to be sent , like if i have to sent an array of years

Comment: @AchalUtkarsh You can create an Injectable Singleton Service. Share this service between the component you are using to set value(s) in the selectedYears variable & the component where you are displaying the value of variable selectedYears, in a newer tab.

Comment: didn't understood regarding this injectable service, do i not need localStorage option, one more thing it's not that the demo-project/checkBirth can only open from this link, inside the application it can be rerouted, this opening in a new tab is a new feature so that user can check data on two screens and edit simultaneously

Comment: You still can use localStorage, by storing an array instead of string.

Answer (score -1):

The easy way is to set data in local storage or session storage and then write the code to pull that data in ngoninit.